# SQLiteAssetHelper cursor query into a String to put in a TextView in my Activity

Tags: java, android, sql, textview, cursor

I am about to freaking blow my brains out if I don't get this and I have no idea what is wrong. I am just trying to get the result from a query into a database file called `Test` that I made from `SQLiteDatabase Browser`.

I have `MyDB` class and my `MainActivity` class which just has a button and a textView (all this is for testing the query so it can be put into my app later). I'am trying to make it so that when you push that button it does the rawQuery in the `MyDB` class and then displays it on the textView. I will have the names for the rows match up with buttons in the app and will then be inserted in the raw query (SQL style) so that It will chose the proper result `story` based on the other columns.

I have tried this same hard coded query in `queryMethodWithout()` in my SQL Browser and it works just fine.

The logCat is giving me

1. `IllegalStateException: could not execute method of the Activity`
2. `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
3. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

With this query I have everything hard coded to specific columns and a speific table just to make sure it all works but It won't print out into the text view, can someone please help?!

I know this is selfish but I am dying right meow!

Cursor from the MyDB class:

```
package com.example.dbquerytester;


import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;


public class MyDB extends SQLiteAssetHelper{



public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Test.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
Context context;




public MyDB(Context applicationContext) {
    super(applicationContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = applicationContext;

}


public Cursor queryMethodWithout(){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String storyQueryWithout1 = "SELECT story FROM Christian WHERE Target = 'Immediate' AND Target2 = 'Mother' AND Variable = 'Courage'";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(storyQueryWithout, null);
    return cursor;

}
```

And here's my MainActivity (The onClickQuery() method is the one that is called when the button is pressed):

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity {

MyDB myDB;
private Cursor cursorQuery;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





}


public void displayMessage(String s){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(s);
}

public void openDB() throws SQLiteException{
    myDB = new MyDB(this);
    myDB.getReadableDatabase();

}

public void onClickQuery(View view){

    openDB();


    cursorQuery = myDB.queryMethodWithout();
    cursorQuery.moveToFirst();
    String story = cursorQuery.getString(0);
    displayMessage(story);
}

protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    cursorQuery.close();
    myDB.close();
}

}
```

Here is my full LogCat!

```
07-17 11:47:34.760: D/(945): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established   0xb823def0, tid 945
07-17 11:47:34.990: W/EGL_emulation(945): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-17 11:47:35.010: D/OpenGLRenderer(945): Enabling debug mode 0
07-17 11:47:37.770: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(945): successfully opened database Test.db
07-17 11:47:37.770: D/AndroidRuntime(945): Shutting down VM
07-17 11:47:37.780: W/dalvikvm(945): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a3dba8)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945): Process: com.example.dbquerytester, PID: 945
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at  android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  ... 11 more
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at com.example.dbquerytester.MyDB.queryMethodWithout(MyDB.java:68)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at com.example.dbquerytester.Main_Activity.onClickQuery(Main_Activity.java:67)
07-17 11:47:37.800: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: when is this displayMessage called. Can you post the stacktrace full.

Comment: What is line 68 `MyDB.java` line ?

Comment: `MyDB` is my database class that extends `SQLiteAssetHelper`, so if its in my Main Activity then is it the reference to that class to pull out the query method. Is that the one you're talking about?

Comment: I FREAKING FIGURED IT OUT!!!!! So of course it was kind of a little thing but what you had to do was to make sure that in your Database in your assets folder, the column that youre pulling from, is set to NOT NULL! although most of you are saying no duh, there could still be some other sheep out there like me who are just as lost so this is a huge day for me!!!!